# Meteor Object doesn't support property or method 'find' in IE 9

Tags: meteor

I've been developing on my Meteor using Chrome and Firefox and everything is working fine. Today I had someone try it with IE 9 and it doesn't load any of the data where these methods are used;

```
//Meteor Object doesn't support property or method 'find'
// in this.find("#cashIn_amt_entered" + acct._id).value below

Template.cashInTotals.helpers({
total: function() {
    var totals = {'budgetTotal':0, 'enteredTotal':0, 'sumTotals':0, 'percOfIncome':0};

    // Get the totals from Cash In
    var cashCursor = cashIn.find({"userID": Meteor.userId(), "dash": Session.get("currentDashboard")});
    cashCursor.forEach( function(acct) {
        totals.budgetTotal = totals.budgetTotal + acct.cashIn_acct_budget;
        totals.sumTotals= totals.sumTotals + acct.cashIn_acct_total;
        totals.enteredTotal = totals.enteredTotal + parseFloat(this.find("#cashIn_amt_entered" + acct._id).value);
    });
    var achieved = 0;
    if (totals.budgetTotal > 0)
    {
        achieved = Math.round(totals.sumTotals/totals.budgetTotal*100);
    }

    var array = [];
    array[0] = {'budgetTotal':totals.budgetTotal, 'enteredTotal':totals.enteredTotal, 'sumTotals':totals.sumTotals, 'percOfIncome':achieved};
    return array;
}
})
```

Meteor is supposed to support IE 8 and up. Any idea why it doesn't understand this one single method? I use `this.find` in 10 different Template helpers to get the data setup, so I really need it!

Comment: Did you try `cashIn.find(/**/)` instead of `this.find(/* ... */)`? Alternatively, you can do `cashCursor.forEach(function(acct){/* ... */}, cashIn)` to explicitly set the context.

Comment: Why not just use jQuery? `$("#cashIn_amt_entered" + acct._id).val()`

Comment: I'll try `cashIn.find` in the morning. Why do people always post answers with jQuery? The jQuery answer failed. jQuery is just a helper for people who don't understand true computer code.

Comment: jQuery is very useful for writing code that is compatible with multiple browsers.

Comment: @LeojPyzynski I completely misunderstood the problem. I read your code as if you were trying to do a collection.find, whereas you're actually searching on the dom. You can either use jquery as suggested, or assign `this` outside your foreach to something else (ie `var self=this;` just before your foreach and then do `self.find`) and use that instead.

Comment: The jQuery method did the trick. I'm always reluctant to drag that package into projects but seeing that it's already there then what the heck! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You lose context when going into the `forEach` loop. So, to fix that, you can either `bind` it or setup a temporary variable to hold the context.

```
Template.cashInTotals.helpers({
total: function() {
    var totals = {'budgetTotal':0, 'enteredTotal':0, 'sumTotals':0, 'percOfIncome':0};

    // Get the totals from Cash In
    var cashCursor = cashIn.find({"userID": Meteor.userId(), "dash": Session.get("currentDashboard")});
    // Store the context of this
    var that = this;
    cashCursor.forEach( function(acct) {
        totals.budgetTotal = totals.budgetTotal + acct.cashIn_acct_budget;
        totals.sumTotals= totals.sumTotals + acct.cashIn_acct_total;
        totals.enteredTotal = totals.enteredTotal + parseFloat(that.find("#cashIn_amt_entered" + acct._id).value);
    });
    var achieved = 0;
    if (totals.budgetTotal > 0)
    {
        achieved = Math.round(totals.sumTotals/totals.budgetTotal*100);
    }

    var array = [];
    array[0] = {'budgetTotal':totals.budgetTotal, 'enteredTotal':totals.enteredTotal, 'sumTotals':totals.sumTotals, 'percOfIncome':achieved};
    return array;
}
})
```

That should fix it.

Comment: That didn't stop it but it does cause the error to be consistent across all browsers.